# Does $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(r+2)}{k!\Gamma(r+2-k)}B_kn^{-k}$ converge, and if so to what?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, bernoulli-numbers

I was wondering if the following series converges:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(r+2)}{k!\Gamma(r+2-k)}B_kn^{-k}\tag1$$

And if so, does it converge to

$$\frac{r+1}{n^{r+1}}\sum_{k=1}^nk^r\tag2$$

Here $B_k$ is the $k^{th}$ Bernoulli number and $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function.  We also have $r\in\mathbb R$ and $n\in\mathbb N$.

It is just my intuition from Faulhaber's formula, but I don't know how to go about working it out, mainly because of $B_k$ and it is rather difficult to get such an expression into WA.

I don't mind if we start with $(2)$ and work backwards to $(1)$, but I still don't think I'm up for this problem.

Comment: Check whether it's a finite sum

Comment: @FelixMarin Well I already know $(1)$ reduces to a finite sum for $n\in\mathbb N$, but the question is what about $n\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio All the formulas there require $p\in\mathbb N$, but here we have $n\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r$ isn't an integer, the series doesn't converge.

Aside from $B_1$, all odd Bernoulli numbers vanish. So we could rewrite the series as
$$
1+\frac{B_1 \Gamma (r+2)}{n \Gamma (r+1)}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(r+2)}{(2k)! \Gamma(r+2-2k)}B_{2k}n^{-2k}
$$Using the Ratio Test, we are interested in the limit
$$
\lim_{k\to \infty}\left|\frac{1}{(2k+2)! \Gamma(r-2k)}B_{2k+2}n^{-2k-2}\cdot \frac{(2k)! \Gamma(r+2-2k)}{B_{2k}}n^{-2k}\right|
$$
$$
=n^{-2}\lim_{k\to \infty}\left|\frac{(2 k-r-1) (2 k-r)}{ (2 k+1)(2k+2)}\cdot \frac{B_{2k+2}}{B_{2k}}\right|
$$Using our assumption $r\notin \mathbb{N}$, we can simplify the rational part.
$$
=1\cdot n^{-2}\lim_{k\to \infty}\left|\frac{B_{2k+2}}{B_{2k}}\right|
$$Using the value of $\zeta(2k)$ and Stirling's formula, one can deduce the asymptotic
$$
|B_{2k}|\sim \sqrt{4\pi k}\left(\frac{k}{\pi e}\right)^{2k}
$$This gives
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{B_{2k+2}}{B_{2k}}\right| = \lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{k^{-2 k-\frac{1}{2}} (k+1)^{2 k+\frac{5}{2}}}{e^2 \pi ^2}\right|=\infty
$$